# how to prevent my application from copying after installation

Tags: c#, wpf

After Installing the application in client system,the application folder should not get copied,even it is copied it should not work in other systems When I click the .exe file. How can I set a password or secure my application files?

Comment: Why do you want to prevent it from running? Are you looking for a licensing system?

Comment: yea  but something at lower cost..

Answer (score 0):

You can add some values to user's registry during installation and in your app's startup check that value.

Comment: i haven't worked with registry keys till now,so please suggest me with procedure for adding keys or type of values to be given at registry

Comment: you can use setup factory (http://www.indigorose.com/products/setup-factory/free-trial-download/) for building your setup file. In that program you can add registry values to user's registry.

Comment: in your program you can read registry key by this way (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18232972/how-to-read-value-of-a-registry-key-c-sharp)

Comment: so you can check that registry and prevent your app from running

Comment: we are using installshield setup currently,how do i set registry values using it ?