# Null in get value from registry

Tags: c#

I want to get value from registry, but value is `null`

I check key in registry and exist in specific path with value

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\MICROSOFT\\WINDOWS");
string st = key.GetValue("LastVerify").ToString();
```

I asked this question before and mark it as duplicate, I find several question about this and I use answers but again have problem.

[question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18232972/how-to-read-value-of-a-registry-key-c-sharp)

[question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36051986/get-value-from-registry)

screnshot of registry:
[image]

Comment: did you try changing the Text-case to match the one in registry?

Comment: could you please paste screenshot of your registry with this property set on `"SOFTWARE\\MICROSOFT\\WINDOWS"`? I can't find such property on my windows node

Comment: @wudzik : i edited the question

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code, just do this and see you have all the Valuenames `string[] valuenames = key.GetValueNames();` ?

Comment: @HariPrasad it's all about accessing different registry modes 32bit vs 64bit

Comment: @SajjadZare let me know if it resolves your issue

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your target machine to x64, because you can't read this values using x86.

```
using (var key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\MICROSOFT\\WINDOWS"))
{
      var value = key.GetValueNames();
}
```

this code works fine under x64.

Here you can find more about accessing registry in x64 and x86 view: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384129.aspx

> By default, a 32-bit application running on WOW64 accesses the 32-bit
>   registry view and a 64-bit application accesses the 64-bit registry
>   view.

If you look at process manager, `regedit.exe` start in 64-bit mode, so it opens different view than your application was using.