# Check how many lines there are of data in a regedit key

Tags: c#, regedit

Hi i want to know how many lines of data there are in a regedit key of the user for example

> Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SystemInformation\ComputerHardwareIds

In my case i have 10 lines of GUID's in there, so how do i do this in c#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From that link [Registry Data Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773476(v=vs.85).aspx) (exists next to value name in registry)

> **REG_SZ**
>   Null-terminated string. It will be a Unicode or ANSI string, depending on whether you use the Unicode or ANSI functions.
>   **REG_MULTI_SZ**
>   Array of null-terminated strings that are terminated by two null characters.

[Depending on that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18232972/how-to-read-value-of-a-registry-key-c-sharp#answer-18234755) just edited it a bit to match your request.

```
using (RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SystemInformation"))
{
    if (key != null)
    {
        object value = key.GetValue("ComputerHardwareIds");
        if (value != null)
        {
            var computerHardwareIds = (value as string[]); // cast value object to string array, because its type is REG_MULTI_SZ

            var lines_num = computerHardwareIds.Length; // then you can get lines number this way

        }
    }
}
```