# How to read registry data from c#

Tags: c#, registry

In my c# program, I'm running a python process. Currently I'm using a hardcoded path for the python.exe, but I want to use the windows registry to return the path to me.

I have found the python path info in the Windows registry under:
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Python\PythonCore\3.7-32\InstallPath`

with some googling I found the following solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18234755/7183609

but when I run my code the variable `key` is always null

```
try
{
    using (RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\\Python\\PythonCore\\3.7-32\\InstallPath"))
    {
        if (key != null)
        {
            // do things
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // do other things
}
```

Am I doing something wrong, do I need to add something to make it work?

Comment: HKEY_CURRENT_USER != Registry.LocalMachine

Comment: @JohnWu thanks, Needed to change Localmachine to CurrentUser

Answer (score 1):

John Wu pointed out that LocalMachine was wrong.

changed

```
using (RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Python\PythonCore\3.7-32\InstallPath"))
```

to

```
using (RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Python\PythonCore\3.7-32\InstallPath"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Registry.CurrentUser instade of Registry.LocalMachine

```
try
    {
        using (RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Python\\PythonCore\\3.7-32\\InstallPath"))
        {
            if (key != null)
            {
                // do things
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // do other things
    }
```