# How can I know the GPU values about DirectX in regedit?

Tags: c#, windows, gpu, directx, regedit

[Regedit Directx informations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eId1I.png)

I have found this register and I need to know how I can do convert and take real values for these items:

- DriverVersion
- LastSeen
- MaxD3D11FeatureLevel
- MaxD3D12FeatureLevel
- SharedSystemMemory
- UDMVersion

I used this to get values, but I don't know the real values after conversion.

```
public void CheckDirectx()
    {
        RegistryKey registerKey;
        string description = string.Empty;
        long driverVersion = -1;
        long lastSeen = -1;
        int d11FeatureLevel = -1;
        int d12FeatureLevel = -1;
        long umdVersion = -1;
        try
        {
            registerKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DirectX\{AA4CC8A5-889A-11E9-B1F8-1062E5C8AC0E}");

            description = registerKey.GetValue("Description") as string;
            driverVersion = (long)registerKey.GetValue("DriverVersion");
            lastSeen = (long)registerKey.GetValue("LastSeen");
            d11FeatureLevel = (int)registerKey.GetValue("MaxD3D11FeatureLevel");
            d12FeatureLevel = (int)registerKey.GetValue("MaxD3D12FeatureLevel");
            umdVersion = (long)registerKey.GetValue("UMDVersion");

        }catch (IOException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}",e.GetType().Name, e.Message);
            return;
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", description);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", lastSeen);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", d11FeatureLevel);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", d12FeatureLevel);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", umdVersion);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read value of a registry key c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18232972/how-to-read-value-of-a-registry-key-c-sharp)

Comment: arent all of those things enumerable from the directx api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of those values can be read with DXGI interfaces (*DXGI_ADAPTER_DESC1* structure and others) and are LARGE_INTEGER.

From the values in your sample, you can convert them like (I get yesterday for your *LastSeen* date) :

```
LARGE_INTEGER nDriverVersion;
nDriverVersion.QuadPart = 0x190015000e0768LL;   
WORD nProduct = HIWORD(nDriverVersion.HighPart);
WORD nVersion = LOWORD(nDriverVersion.HighPart);
WORD nSubVersion = HIWORD(nDriverVersion.LowPart);
WORD nBuild = LOWORD(nDriverVersion.LowPart);

LARGE_INTEGER nLastSeen;
nLastSeen.QuadPart = 0x1D51F80F1EA7FB1LL;
FILETIME ft;
ft.dwLowDateTime = nLastSeen.LowPart;
ft.dwHighDateTime = nLastSeen.HighPart;
SYSTEMTIME st;
FileTimeToSystemTime(&ft, &st);
```