# How to make dependencies on Toggle Button C#

Tags: c#, button

So i have Toggle Button.
How to make program check some function if its 1 or 2, and then make Switch true or false depending on it (1 or 2)
I have Toggle Button from siticone.

Comment: Can you please explain more about your problem as its a bit unclear from your situation what exactly you are trying.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/DvmTlwg I have this kind of toggle button. How to make program read certain registry dword and then make it turned on/off depending on dword value

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @RobertMastyl you just have to read the registry first that won't be hard to find here if you try to search for it. For your ease [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18232972/how-to-read-value-of-a-registry-key-c-sharp) you can see how to read registries. After reading the value it won't be hard to make a switch condition or even a if-else condition.